# Fancybox plugin appears to cache results

Tags: linq, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using a fancybox plugin on one of my ASP MVC views to display error messages via an Ajax call. However, it appears to be caching the results. Below is the Linq query I use to retrieve errors from the table

```
    public JsonResult GetErrors(string term)
    {
        try
        {
            int id = int.Parse(term);

            var errors = (from e in db.TransmissionHistory
                          where (e.TransmissionTable == TABLE) &&
                                (e.TranTableId == id) &&
                                (e.ReplyResult == RESULT)
                          orderby e.TransmittedOn descending
                          select e).FirstOrDefault();

            if (errors == null)
            {
                return Json("Search returned no results", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            List<string> errs = new List<string>();

            errs = errors.Errors.Split(',').ToList();

            return Json(errs, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Json("There was an error processing your request, please try again", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        } 
    }
```

If I set a breakpoint at the first line: `int id = int.Parse(term);`
this code will only execute the first time I click on the pic that initiates the fancybox/Ajax call. Consequently, this winds up being the only information that is displayed in the fancybox modal.

The `linq` query is supposed to grab the most recent error message (as determined by the date field), however if a new error message occurs after you initiate the fancybox/ajax call you will not see it. Instead the results of the previous query are simply displayed again. Also, to reiterate, in this instance (initiating the call a second time) the breakpoint does not fire.

I'm not very familiar with this plugin, so I would assume this means that I am somehow caching the results of the call. However, I couldn't find much on the net detailing fancybox's caching properties and/or how to alter them. For good measure, here is the fancybox jquery:

```
        $('.checkErrors').click(function () {
            var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var firstName = $tr.find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
            var lastName = $tr.find('td:nth-child(3)').text();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetErrors","AgentTransmission")',
                data: { term: $(this).attr('id') },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var display = "<center><h2>" + firstName + " " + lastName + "</h2></center><ul>";

                    if (data == "Search returned no results" || data == "There was an error processing your request, please try again") {
                        display += "<li>" + data + "</li>";
                    } else {
                        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                            display += "<li>" + value + "</li>";
                        });
                    }

                    display += "</ul>";

                    $.fancybox(display, {
                        // fancybox API options
                        fitToView: false,
                        autoScale: true,
                        autoDimension: true,
                        closeClick: true,
                        openEffect: 'fade',
                        closeEffect: 'fade',
                        closeBtn: true,
                        openSpeed: 'fast',
                        closeSpeed: 'fast'
                    });
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    $.fancybox("There was an error processing your request. We apologize for the inconvenience!", {
                        // fancybox API options
                        fitToView: false,
                        autoScale: true,
                        autoDimension: true,
                        closeClick: true,
                        openEffect: 'fade',
                        closeEffect: 'fade',
                        closeBtn: true,
                        openSpeed: 'fast',
                        closeSpeed: 'fast'
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a result  of the caching property not being set on the Ajax call, not fancybox. Simply adding `cache: false` to the ajax call fixed the issue.

Comment: about to say that. I guess you can accept your own answer and close the case.